# Custom failure messages in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, terminal, console

In my RSpec + Capybara tests, when I'm `expecting` something but the test fails, I'd like to have some custom messages.

I achieved it with:

```
it "a test" do
 do_something
 expect(current_path).to eq('/some/path'), "expected path to be 'some_path' but fails"
end
```

but what I'd like to have is ONLY my custome message, without the **Failure/Error** line from RSpec

[image: console]

Is this possible?

Comment: you can check this http://makandracards.com/makandra/22095-custom-error-messages-in-rspec-or-cucumber-steps

Comment: hey @punticse , this is what I tried. It does work but what I'd need is to hide the line "Failure/Error: expect(current_path)..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to customize the ouput, you should write a custom formatter. Base example:

```
class MyFormatter
  RSpec::Core::Formatters.register self, :example_failed

  def initialize(output)
    @output = output
  end

  def example_failed(notification)
    @output << "EPIC FAIL! => #{notification.exception}"
  end
end
```

Don't forget to require your formatter file and run your suite with `--format MyFormatter`.

You could find a more complex example here: http://eftimov.net/how-to-write-rspec-formatters-from-scratch

Or find inspiration with other popular formatters:

- https://github.com/mattsears/nyan-cat-formatter
- https://github.com/cupakromer/emoji-rspec

Comment: thanks @markets!

is there a way to change the output for a single test?