# How to append custom message to RSpec exception message

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is there a way to prefix/append custom message to the RSpec Exception?

```
expect(products).to match_array expected_products
```

I am aware that I can pass an extra exception message param to the above expectation but I don't want to have my own exception but to add something to the RSpec exception which I'd like to retain. So above statement would normally raise `expected [...] to match [...] missing...extra...` which I find useful but I would like to have for e.g. Customer ID added to the message e.g. `CUSTOMER ID: 12345 -  expected [...] to match [...] missing...extra...` perhaps by monkey patching?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom failure messages in Rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288211/custom-failure-messages-in-rspec)

Comment: Not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45785978/how-to-append-custom-message-to-rspec-exception-message.  Custom messages for exceptions/errors raised cannot be handled the same way as other custom messages.

Answer (score 2):

You can monkey patch [`handle_failure`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/d7c74ef3843866acf3165fc500b2c6f1a3c290ee/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb#L33-L43) method.

```
module MyExpectationHelper
  def self.handle_failure(matcher, message, failure_message_method)
    message = message.call if message.respond_to?(:call)
    message ||=''
    message += matcher.__send__(failure_message_method) #changes ||= to += to prepend message
    if matcher.respond_to?(:diffable?) && matcher.diffable?
      ::RSpec::Expectations.fail_with message, matcher.expected, matcher.actual
    else
      ::RSpec::Expectations.fail_with message
    end
  end
end

describe 'append message' do
  module RSpec
    module Expectations
      module ExpectationHelper
        def self.handle_failure(matcher, message, failure_message_method)
          MyExpectationHelper.handle_failure(matcher, message, failure_message_method)
        end
      end
    end
  end
  it 'should contain the message' do
    expect(products).to match_array expected_products, 'CUSTOMER ID: 12345 -  '
  end
end
```